# Apache won't stop

Tags: apache-2.2, amazon-ami

This is on an Amazon Linux instance (apparently based on CentOS 6)

```
# service httpd restart
Stopping httpd:                                            [FAILED]
Starting httpd: (98)Address already in use: make_sock: could not bind to address [::]:8080
(98)Address already in use: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:8080
no listening sockets available, shutting down
Unable to open logs
                                                           [FAILED]
```

Obviously it won't start since the stop failed. But, why wouldn't it stop in the first place?  I can type "service httpd stop" over and over again and it just keeps printing [FAILED].  "killall httpd" works fine.

After doing a kill and a service httpd start, stop works normally again for a while.  Most disconcerting.

```
Server version: Apache/2.2.24 (Unix)
Server built:   May 20 2013 21:12:45
```

Comment: It's related to restarting via an rpm %post script.  Still don't know why exactly, but I've written a script that does a very detailed shutdown/restart. Hopefully I've accounted for all the edge cases.

Answer (score 3):

Are you doing anything to cleanup/delete the service lockfile?  It's probably stored at /var/run/httpd.pid.  If that gets removed, the CentOS service infrastructure doesn't know that Apache is running, or what process ID it's using.  So it fails to stop it.

Comment: Not me. I do have some rpms that would try to restart apache, I wonder if they are trying to do it at the same time and that's somehow messing things up. I figured they'd go one after the other but maybe it's trying to run them in parallel.

Comment: Alternately, if it's restarting Apache without using `service apache restart`, that might result in changing the PID values.  (eg:  by using `kill` or `apachectl` directly)

Comment: apachectl manages the pid file correctly.

Comment: Yup, you're right.  (I clearly never use that)